# Python Pandas: create new column contains date range

Tags: python, pandas

I have hotel DataFrame with 2 columns: check-in & check-out. I would like to create new column that contains series of date, start from check-in to check-out.

[image]

example: check in = 2019-10-02, check out = 2019-10-04.
new column should has date series: 2019-10-02, 2019-10-03, 2019-10-04. Apply same logic for every row. Please advise how should I do it with Python Pandas.

Comment: [pd.date_range(x, y) for x , y in zip(df.check-in,df.check_out)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your both columns are available in datetime series.

Below code shoud give you a range in **required format** with new column.

```
df['range'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['check_in'], x['check_out']).format('%Y-%m-%d')[1:], axis=1)
```

Comment: both codes work for me, only difference is date format. I would like to ask: (1) could we use range(check_in, check_out) instead of pd.date_range()? (2) the "x" in lambda x: pd.date_range(x['check_in'], x['check_out']; is this referred to the dataframe? (3) I tried doing this way: pd.date_range(df['check_in'], df['check_out']) with an error: TypeError: Cannot convert input [0      2018-07-01. What could be the reason? (4) what is the difference between using pd.date_range() with apply() and without apply()?

Comment: 1) range() cannot be used for string, it only accepts integer as a input. 2) Yes, you can check lambda syntax online 3) df['check_in'] this returns a Series and pd.date_time does not accept that. It accept a string formated as a date 4) The apply() function is used to apply a function along an axis of the DataFrame or Series. In this case axis1 (column) for check_in&check_out column.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df['check_in'] = pd.to_datetime(df['check_in'])
df['check_out'] = pd.to_datetime(df['check_out'])
df['range'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(pd.date_range(x['check_in'], x['check_out'])), axis=1)
print(df)

    check_in  check_out                                              range
0 2019-10-02 2019-10-04  [2019-10-02 00:00:00, 2019-10-03 00:00:00, 201...
```